# Selecting Latest Row in multiple Entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with below kind of Data.

[image]

Now I want to select the Data acording to latest DateAdded for each Database per Servername and Instance name.

Expected Data is

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please post data in the question, not as an image. Which DBMS?

Comment: it' MS SQL Server

Comment: here i have mentioned only 1 server...but i have many no. of servers in my actual table

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
select
Database ,
Servername,
max(dateadded)
from table_db
group by Database ,Servername
```

Comment: here  I Need all the columns in the result...and for that we will have to add other columns also in Group by clause

Comment: and in that case it will give duplicate data

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
select serverName, 
       InstanceName, 
       DBName, 
       RecoveryModel,
       DateAdded, 
       LastBackupDate, 
       LastDifferentialBackupDate, 
       LastLogBackupDate
from ( 
       select serverName, 
              InstanceName, 
              DBName, 
              RecoveryModel,
              DateAdded, 
              LastBackupDate, 
              LastDifferentialBackupDate, 
              LastLogBackupDate, 
              row_number() over(partition by serverName,DBname order by DateAdded desc) as rn 
      from DB.databaseinfo 
                            ) X 
      where X.rn=1 
      order by X.serverName,X.InstanceName,DBName
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select      *

from       (select      *
                       ,row_number ( ) over 
                       (
                            partition by  Servername,InstanceName,DBName
                            order by      DateAdded desc
                        ) as rn

            from        MyTable 
            ) t

where       rn = 1
;
```

Comment: It's not picking all Databases

Comment: Have you checked it after I added the InstanceName to the "partition by"?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz You will have to add `DBname` to `partition by`

Comment: I used this:  select * from (
    select
        serverName, InstanceName, DBName, RecoveryModel,DateAdded, LastBackupDate, LastDifferentialBackupDate,
   LastLogBackupDate,
        row_number() over(partition by DBname order by DateAdded desc) as rn
    from
        DB.databaseinfo 
) t where t.rn=1   order by t.InstanceName

Comment: This doent include all database

Comment: @VivekGarg, this are just technicalities. if you want a record per X,Y,Z than put X,Y,Z in the PARTITION BY clause. The question is not clear enough.

Comment: @VivekGarg, updated query to partition by Servername,InstanceName,DBName

Comment: @VivekGarg. Great :-) Just remember the pattern of this query, there's a good chance you'll use it again